# Creating a link to the latest release with maven's deploy plugin

Tags: maven-2

My pom.xml contains:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>ssh-myown-repository</id>
    <url>scpexe://user@host/path/to/repository</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

So whenever I issue:

```
mvn deploy
```

My project is, well, deployed properly on my remote repository, under a name such as this:

```
http://host/repository/project/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/project-0.7.0-20120518.212052-3.jar
```

I know file "maven-metadata.xml" contains information about which file is the latest release, but I'd very much like the mvn deploy stage to create a link to the latest jar file, say:

```
http://host/repository/project/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/project-0.7.0-latest.jar
```

I understand "scpexe" has no way of doing this directly as links are part of the file system on which the web server is running (ie.: they are not represented as uploadable file content).

I have shell access on this remote server, so is there a way to hook on maven's deploy action to execute a script after deployment is complete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that the **-SNAPSHOT** is a thing like the "LATEST". Furthermore i recommend to use a repository manager.